# Winforms- Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

All,

I am facing a technical issue and please find the details below.

Development Environment

- OS                       : Windows 7
- Tool                     : MS Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition
- Targeted Framework       : 3.5 CE
- Targeted OS              : Windows Mobile 5.0 pocket PC
- Language             : VB.NET

**Issue in Detail**

There are three forms

1. frmA
2. frmB
3. frmC

Steps

1. All forms are implemented by a custom interface called Iforms.
2. There is a List to store all the forms during runtime.
3. frmA is the first form added to list and displays the form using Form.Showdialog
       objFrmA.ShowDialog()
4. From FormA contains a button and on click , checks whether the List contains the instance of type FormB, if it is available then get the instance else create a new instance and add to list. Then uses formB.ShowDialog ().
5. From formB  contains a button and on click , checks whether the List contains the instance of type FormC, if it is available then get the instance else create a new instance and add to list. Then uses formC.ShowDialog ().
6. So all the form instances are avail in the List
7. From C I need to show the Form B, So I check whether the List contains the formB's instance and since it is available, it will call frmB.ShowDialog().
8. Then it throws an error.
   "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Comment: Although your explanations are pretty detailed (thanks for that), the idea (and, mainly, the problem) cannot be properly understood without the code. Can you please post your code?

Comment: This is undiagnosable from the question, asking for help for an exception requires posting at least the exception's stack trace.  The only obvious lead is that you didn't describe a mechanism to get a form object removed from the list again.  So you might be using an instance that's already dead because it got disposed.  Use the FormClosed event to remove it from the list.